wordpress installation as subdirectory by nginx on ubuntu server
I have an ubuntu vps.
I have set a domain and running an app by nginx on the domain route: example.com.
Now want to have a wordpress blog by installing on subdirectory by nginx with this route:
example.com/blog.
What should I do to solve this problem?
server {
server_name example.com;

gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_min_length 256;

        location /_next/static/ {
                alias /home/username/apps/my-app/.next/static/;
                expires 365d;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #change to 3001 for second app, but make sure second nextjs app starts on new port in packages.json "start": "next start -p 3001",
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

   
location /blog {
   # what should I do or add what block to solve my problem and have the wordpress on subdirectory?
}



}

I am able to do it on a domain-route or subdomain; But is not possible for me personally, to do what do I want.
Please help me to solve, if you know something... Thanks!
